# Inequality Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

With $\| y_n \| = \sum_{k=1}^{n} |< x, e_k>|^2 \leq \|x\|^2  \forall 1\leq n$, prove that $| \langle x,y\rangle |\leq\|x\|\|y\|$

Let $x,y \in X$ 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} |< x, e_k>|^2 \leq \|x\|^2$$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} |< x, e_k>|^2 \leq \|x\|^2\|y\|^2$$
$$|< x, e_k>|^2 \leq \|x\|^2\|y\|^2$$

Help me please to continue

Comment: Not sure what $x$, $y$ are -- elements of a Hilbert or inner product space?  Not sure what $e_k$ are either.  Not sure how $y_n$ relates to $y$; it seems to be the sum of squares of absolute values of inner products of $x$ with the $e_k$'s, whatever *they* are.

Comment: Then I will find a $e_k$ ?

Comment: Como Ud. parece ser ecuatoriano le respondo en castellano. Ud. usa varios símbolos sin explicar lo que son.  Para que alguien le ayude, tiene primero que decirnos qué significan los símbolos que está utilizando.  Anda buscando una demostración cualquiera de la desigualdad de Cauchy-Schwartz?  O tiene en mente una demostración especifica donde intervienen de algún modo $e_k$ (tal vez una base de algún tipo)?

Comment: usando la primera desigualdad  demostrar la desigualdad de Cauchy Shwarz y  los $e_k$ son elemntos de una base ortonormal.